# How to add values in a new column in Pandas by using kind of VLOOKUP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, vlookup

I am working on a project for analysing Amazon marketing campaign data sets. The campaigns have the hierachie:

"Camapigns" includes 
"AdGroups" includes 
"Keywords".

While I can see a performance value for all of the record types (Campaign, Adgroup and Keyword) the change of the "Bid" is only possible on the record type keyword. The actual campaign has 17.000 rows and several different campaigns etc., however, I created a sample version here:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Record Type': ['Campaign','AdGroup','Keyword','Keyword','Keyword'],
     'Campaign':['Test_Campaign','Test_Campaign','Test_Campaign','Test_Campaign','Test_Campaign'],
     'AdGroup':['','AdGroup_A','AdGroup_A','AdGroup_A','AdGroup_A'],
     'Keyword':['','','Keyword_A','Keyword_B','Keyword_C'],
     'Bid':['NA','NA',1,1,1],
     'Performance':['0.3','0.9',0.6,1.1,1.3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

What I want the programme to do:

1) Check the performance of the 'Record Type' AdGroup. If performance has a specific condition (for example if performance < 1) the bid of the 'Record Type' keyword should be changed (for example +10 %).

My idea:

1. Create a new column that is a combination of the values "campaign_AdGroup" (then we have a singular value for each AdGroup, because an AdGroup with the same name could be in another campaign).
2. Create a further column with a value of the action "Action" (for example: 110 %, because we want to raise the keyword with 10 %).

   3. In the last step I would iterate through all the 'Record Type' keyword and do a VLOOKUP for the combination of "campaign + AdGroup". If a result is found in 'Action', the bid of the specific keyword should be multiplied with the "Action" value.

Do you have any suggestions for step 3.? Here is the last code:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Record_Type': ['Campaign','AdGroup','Keyword','Keyword','Keyword'],'Campaign':['Test_Campaign','Test_Campaign',
                    'Test_Campaign','Test_Campaign','Test_Campaign'],'AdGroup':['','AdGroup_A','AdGroup_A','AdGroup_A','AdGroup_A']
    ,'Keyword':['','','Keyword_A','Keyword_B','Keyword_C'],'Bid':['NA','NA',1,1,1],'Performance':[0.3,0.9,0.6,1.1,1.3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df ['Action'] = 1
df ['Help'] = df['Record_Type'] + df['Campaign']
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a apply lambda function.
i.e.

```
df["Action"] = df.apply(lambda r: 1.1 if r["Record_Type"] == "AdGroup" and r["Performance"] < 1 else r["Action"], axis=1)
```

You could also use iloc with a condition.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but now it is not a solution for the problem. Because: If the performance value of an AdGroup is < 1, I want to change the Bid of each Keyword that is part of this AdGroup. 
The iteration must be in 2 steps:

1) Check the performance on the AdGroup Level and save information if there is a change for the value bid for the keywords is required. The saved data could be a data-set of "Campaign" + "AdGroup" and the Action.

2) In the second step all of 'Record_Type' keyword needs to be checked. If "Campaign" + "AdGroup" of the keyword is in the list before, action

Comment: must be taken on the keyword level. For example in this case: The performance of the 'AdGroup_A' is 0.9. We need to save the information "Test_CampaignAdGroup_A" and the "Action" value "1.1". In the second step we need to check all 'Record_Type' keyword. For each keyword the combination of "campaign" + "AdGroup" is also built. Now it must be kind of VLOOKUP on the same data at AdGroup and if there is a action, the action needs to be multiplied with the bid of the keyword. In this case all keyword must be multiplied with 1.1.